# Using mdDialog with ng-repeat keeps displaying the same information from first click

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, servicenow, angularjs-material, mddialog

Our team is building an app in ServiceNow and using AngularJS Material.  We built a questionnaire that allows users to make edits to answers at the end.  For the questions that can be edited, we're trying to use mdDialog that brings up a modal window where a user can edit their answers.  The issue we're running into is that when a user clicks to edit an answer, then closes that modal to open up another answer to edit, the modal opens the first answer every time.  We can't seem to close that scope to open another one.

In our HTML, we have a pencil glyphicon that has an ng-click for a function editQuestionFnct:

```
<td rowspan="2" style="color: #979797; padding-right: 15px; cursor: pointer;" ng-click="editQuestionFnct(item.quest_id)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" title="Edit Answer" style="padding-right: 5px;"></span></td>
```

That editQuestionFnct passes in several items into the showPrerenderedDialog function that generates the modal:

```
$scope.editQuestionFnct = function(val){
        $scope.editWidget = {};
        spUtil.get("gateway_questionnaire_widget", {//call new instance of this widget
            task_id: $scope.data.task_id,
            quest_id: val,
            request: 'edit',
            taskTable: $scope.data.task_table,
            questionnaire_table: $scope.params.questionnaireTable,
            serviceID: $scope.params.serviceID,
            refID: $scope.params.refID,
            taskCompleted: false,
            editRequest: true
        }).then(function(response) {
            $scope.editWidget = response;//var to hold widget response to display in modal
            $scope.showPrerenderedDialog('#editQuestion');
        });
    }
```

The showPrerenderedDialog function renders the modal:

```
$scope.showPrerenderedDialog = function(name) {
    $mdDialog.show({
        contentElement: name,
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        clickOutsideToClose:true
    });
};
```

Here is the md-dialog template:

```
<div style="visibility: hidden">
    <div class="md-dialog-container" id="editQuestion">
      <md-dialog style="background-color: #ffffff;" aria-label="edit dialog">
        <md-toolbar style="background-color: #022C68; width: 100%;">
          <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools" style="color: #ffffff;">Edit Response</h1>
        </md-toolbar> 
        <md-dialog-content style="background-color: #ffffff;">
          <!--<div id="editQuestDiv" style="min-width: 700px;">-->
            <sp-widget widget="editWidget"></sp-widget>
          <!--</div>-->
        </md-dialog-content>
        <md-dialog-actions layout="row">
          <span flex></span>
          <md-button ng-click="closeDialog()" class="md-primary md-raised">
            Close
          </md-button>
        </md-dialog-actions>
      </md-dialog>
    </div>
```

What am i missing from the above code so that I can open one modal for a specific question and then open up another modal with another question?  Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like it might be passing the same `item.quest_id` to `editQuestionFnct(item.quest_id)` on every click.

Comment: Thanks @brt! Yea, that's what I'm thinking as well; any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I'm guessing that `<td>` is part of an `ng-repeat` ? Probably something with the placement of the `ng-repeat` is not iterating all the `item`s, so the same `quest_id` is getting set.

Comment: hey brt, I've put in an alert for val (alert(val)) just to see if quest_id is changing with each click and it is.  I also console.log(response) and everything is passing in correctly.  So it looks like all the information needed for the modal is being passed in correctly, but mddialog refuses to display the correct question after the first click...

Comment: maybe this line? `$scope.showPrerenderedDialog('#editQuestion');`  I haven't used mdDialog, but are you passing in a string instead of a variable here?

Comment: Or maybe whatever service is being hit by `spUtil.get()` isn't using the `val` correctly.  I'd set a breakpoint inside the `.then()` to see what my `response` looks like.

Comment: $scope.showPrerenderedDialog('#editQuestion'); -- I'm passing in a string which is the id of the md-dialog I want to show.  I also put in a console.log(response) and it looks like everything is passing through correctly...this is all very weird lol

Comment: if the response is coming back correctly, maybe the variable binding in md-dialog is off?  I'm assuming it opens a template with `{{variables}}` in it?